# Getting Webview Activity to Disappear with PDF Link Action_view

Tags: android, pdf, download, webview

I'm downloading a PDF in my application using:

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("*url for your pdf*"));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

This opens an activity that looks like a webview and begins the pdf download in the drop down menu.  I'd like to keep the drop down download notification but is there a way to close the webview activity once the download starts? Or even better keep the webview from popping up in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of calling a Uri intent, you could [download the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921262/how-to-download-and-save-a-file-from-internet-using-java) to the sd card if it is not already there (using notification for progress), then call action_view on the file. That should open it directly in the preferred PDF viewer.